# Dedicate RAM to integrated Intel GMA4500 video card

Tags: memory, graphics-card

Would it be possible to force a RAM dedication to the GMA4500 intel video card in my hp 6730b. I know it's a business laptop, not meant for gaming etc... But that's what I want to do if anyone can tell me how to

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some laptops have a setting in the BIOS for this, on others the allocation of memory is handled automatically (RAM is allocated as needed) and there's no option to change the amount.

Edit: According to [this thread](http://www.overclock.net/graphics-cards-general/463434-set-gma4500-memory-usage.html) you should have a BIOS option for setting the reserved memory.